# I dont know what im doing wrong with my lambda expression, can someone correct me?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm using FrameworkEntity and have two classes:

```
public class InfoComplementarEmpresaModel
{
    public int idempresa { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string idcomplemento { get; set; }

    public string idinformacao { get; set; }
    public string conteudocomplemento { get; set; }
    public string periodocomplemento { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class InfoComplementarModel
{
    public int idlayout { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int idinformacao { get; set; }

    public string codigoinformacao { get; set; }
    public string descricaoinformacao { get; set; }
    public int tipoinformacao { get; set; }
}
```

The lambda join im trying to do is the following:

```
public List<string> GetTipoENomeDeInformacaoComplementarEmpresa(string idDaEmpresa)
{
    List<string> listaDeTipos = new List<string>();
    int idDaEmpresaNoFormatocerto = Convert.ToInt32(idDaEmpresa);

    listaDeTipos.Add("Criar novo preenchimento de valores");

    var nomesDeInformacoes = db.InformacoesComplementaresDaEmpresa
        .Where(a => a.idempresa == idDaEmpresaNoFormatocerto)
        .Join(db.InformacoesComplementaresDoLayout,
            infocompempresa => new {infocompempresa.idinformacao},
            infocomplayout => new {infocomplayout.idinformacao},
            (ice, icl) => ice.idinformacao)
        .ToList();

    // some method that will put nomesDeInformacoes in listaDeTipos

    return listaDeTipos;
}
```

The Join accuses "The type arguments for method Queryable.Join(IQueryable, IQueryable, Expression>, Expression>, Expression>) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"

Comment: You didn't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: Probably because you are returning List<string> your join looks like it will create an anonymous type no ?

Comment: To return `listaDeTipos` along with the `nomesDeInformacoes`, you can add the line of code: `listaDeTipos.AddRange(nomesDeInformacoes);` before your `return` statement.

Comment: Can you say why you are using anonymous types here?  That seems like a strange thing to do.

Comment: While trying to use Entity Framework, anonymous types are what i faced with the most, so just ran with it, Eric Lippert. 
That's what it used to have, Rufus L. i removed it because my main problem is with the Join statement

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT

there were various problems:

idinformacao in InfoComplementarEmpresaModel was a string instead of a int

Then i discovered that ALL the anonymous names in the join must remain the same, resulting in:

```
var nomesDeInformacoes = db.InformacoesComplementaresDaEmpresa.Where(a => a.idempresa == idDaEmpresaNoFormatocerto)
                                                                      .Join(db.InformacoesComplementaresDoLayout,
                                                                            ice => ice.idinformacao ,
                                                                            icl => icl.idinformacao ,
                                                                            (ice, icl) =>  new { ice, icl } )
                                                                      .Select(
                                                                      //creating a class to accept the fields i want  
                                                                      })
                                                                      .ToList();
```

This guy works, returning in the class im creating.